# AJAX при коде ответа 200 (ок) заходит в error, а не в success

Tags: javascript, ajax

```
       // base url
       const url = "http://localhost:5002/api/contacts/"; 

       // send put request to the api
        $.ajax({
            headers: {
                'Accept': 'application/json',
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            },

            type: 'DELETE',
            url: url + contactId,
            dataType: 'json',

            success: function () {
                // come back to main page
                window.location.href = '/contacts/list'
            },

            error: function (error) {
                console.log(error);
            }
        });
```

При этом, вот что выводится в консоли

`status: 200
statusCode: ƒ (e)
statusText: "OK"`

Код метода в апи

```
    // DELETE api/contacts/2
    [HttpDelete("{id}")]
    public ActionResult Delete(int id)
    {
        using (var db = new PhonebookDBContext())
        {
            var con = db.Contacts.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Id == id);

            if (con != null)
            {
                db.Contacts.Remove(con);
                db.SaveChanges();

                return Ok();
            }

            return NotFound("Not found contact with a same Id");
        }
    }
```

Comment: посмотри текст ошибки, скорее всего, так как ничего не возвращается он не смог ничего перевести в объект и упал. Текст ошибки стоит добавить в сам вопрос.

Comment: Нет ошибки. Статус 200. Ответ "Ok". А метод срабатывает, контакт удаляется.

Comment: ты уверен что это вывод `console.log(error);`, обработчик ошибки кстати три параметра принимает, стоит их все вывести. Добавь скрин того, что выведется

Comment: какие именно  параметры

Comment: Все три и выведи, нужен результат для вот такого кода: `error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                console.log(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown);
            }`

Comment: в первом - это объект, в котором статус - 200

Comment: Ну как я и сказал, jquery попытался разобрать ответ как json, и упал, так как в ответе ничего

Comment: а второй - "parse error"

Comment: [_dataType: The type of data that you're **expecting back from the server**._](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) - ты поставит `json`, вот и идет попытка ответ преобразовать в объект.

Comment: спасибо, помогло

Comment: Напиши ответ, если разобрался и решил

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нужно убрать строку `dataType: 'json'`, т.к jquery пытался разобрать объект, который не приходит в ответе